# NSDictionary object without root key name, how do I iterate through entries?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSDictionary with the following structure

```
"2" = (
  "multi" = "1",
  "catID" = "2"
      )
"3" = (
  "multi" = "1",
  "catID = "3"
      )
```

Is it possible to get all "catID" values in a new array?

Comment: Actually, that's not a NSDictionary.  In fact, I can't tell what it is.

Comment: What do you mean by a "root key"? From your example it looks like your keys are numbers and your values contain a "catID" with the same number.

Comment: But if you have an NSDictionary that looks sort of like that you can find out how to process it by actually consulting the documentation.  Everything you need to know is there.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a dictionary containing dictionaries. The outer dictionary has keys "2" and "3". Each inner dictionary has keys "multi" and "catID".

If I'm right, and you want an array containing the value for the "multi" key in each inner dictionary, you could build that using the NSDictionary method `-enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`. You'd create an empty mutable array outside the block, then inside the block you'd fetch the value for the current object's "multi" key and add it to your array.

Note that dictionaries are unordered collections, so the order of the resulting array would not be defined.

If the keys to the outer dictionary are always string values for integers, you could instead write code that used a for loop to loop through the numeric value of each key, built a string version of that number, fetched the inner dictionary for that value, and appended the value of that dictionary's "multi" key to the array.

However, I'm speculating. Your description was vague and did not match the data you provided in your original post.

Answer (score -1):

I got it by using allValues (I was stuck with allKeys)

```
NSArray *values = [itemElements allValues];
NSLog(@"Values:%@",[values valueForKey:@"catID"]);
```